# Ionic: Why are my images not loading from my json file?

Tags: javascript, json, ionic-framework, photos

I'm trying to load images from my json file into my application but i cannot get it to work:

Here's my code:

js:

```
.controller('photoCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicBackdrop, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $http) {
   $scope.images = [];

    $scope.getImages = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/37ia6')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.images = data.images;
            })
    }
```

html:

```
<ion-view view-title="Gallery" align-title="center" ng-controller="photoCtrl" >

  <ion-content ng-init="getImages()" class="center" class="has-header padding">

    <!-- start Under6/7/8/9s Photos -->
    <div class="item item-divider">
      <i class="ion-images"></i> Under6/7/8/9s Photos
    </div>
    <a class="item item-list-detail">
      <ion-scroll direction="x">
        <img on-hold="onHold()" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{images.src}}" ng-click="showImages($index)" class="image-list-thumb" />
      </ion-scroll>
    </a>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: i see the first 3 images loading. Maybe its worth creating a minimal example, where you load images from your JSON file without any fancy stuff around. Maybe there is some something wrong with the JSON, but it might be that its not really the JSON file that makes problems but some other part.

Comment: Oh opps, i added the wrong codepen! http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/QbBdVw

Comment: @smither123 You have a typo: `ng-src="{{ image.src }}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is in your JSON. What would you expect to happen when iterating over:

```
{"images":"http://cdn.caughtoffside.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Marko-Marin.jpg"}
```

Probably your API should return an array of objects like

```
[{"src":"http://cdn.caughtoffside.com/.../Marko-Marin.jpg"},
 {"src":"http://cdn.caughtoffside.com/.../Johnny-Blue.jpg"},
 ...
]
```

Iterating over an object usually looks different:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myObj">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" ng-repeat="image in images"> 
  <img on-hold="onHold()" ng-src="{{image.src}}" ng-click="showImages($index)" class="image-list-thumb" /> 
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: @smither123 Are you sure the `images` is returning valid data? Can you open up a inspector debugger and see if the code is generating proper HTML?

Comment: I have created a new codepen with a similar json file. Hopefully this will help. http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/QbBdVw